# Is the fist argument register in this diagram of x86_64 register wrong?

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers

I got a diagram of register from CS:APP 3rd Edition:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbnAd.png)
which says %rdi as the first argument. However, when I compile the following code in asmtry.c

```
long Q(long x);

long P(long x,long y)
{
    long u = Q(y);
    long v = Q(x);
    return u + v;
}
```

with gcc command "gcc -Og -S asmtry.c ", I got asmtry.s as follows

```
    .file   "asmtry.c"
    .text
    .globl  P
    .def    P;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   P
P:
    pushq   %rsi
    .seh_pushreg    %rsi
    pushq   %rbx
    .seh_pushreg    %rbx
    subq    $40, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 40
    .seh_endprologue
    movl    %ecx, %esi
    movl    %edx, %ecx
    call    Q
    movl    %eax, %ebx
    movl    %esi, %ecx
    call    Q
    addl    %ebx, %eax
    addq    $40, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rsi
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .ident  "GCC: (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0"
    .def    Q;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
```

Before calling Q, command "movl %ecx, %esi " and "movl  %edx, %ecx" indicate that %ecx, or saying %rcx is the first argument. Is the diagram at the beginning wrong or out of time? Where can I get the latest register diagram of x86_64?
Besides, what dose command "subq    $40, %rsp" do?

Comment: SYS V ABI uses `rdi` as the first arg register. Windows uses `rcx`. You are using MinGW so you must obey the Windows ABI. You should be able to use WLS for a true "Linux experience" under Windows if you don't want to use a VM. The **instruction** `sub $40, %rsp` subtracts 40 from `rsp` to allocate space on the stack (which only grows and shrinks by moving the stack pointer).

Comment: SEH is a Windows thing.  `.seh_pushreg    %rsi` indicates you're probably compiling for Windows.  On, and the `.ident` string confirms it.